# NUnit Test Adapter 2 assembly not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nunit

I'm facing with a strange issue with Visual Studio 2012 Update 5.
I have to add Unit tests to an existing project and I have installed NUnit 2 Test Adapter via Tools->Extension Manager.
The intallation works fine and Visual studio is restarted but I cannot find the NUnit assembly to add to my test project.
Where I'm wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which NUnit assembly are you unable to find / add ? NUnit framework? NUnit test adapter? (Normally, only the framework is added to a project.)

Comment: NUnit framework. When I try to add a reference to NUnit I cannot find the assembly in the GAC or other folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter is... well, an adapter... It allows you to run NUnit tests within Visual Studio by making them look like tests that VS understands.

In order to write NUnit tests, you have to actually install NUnit. Probably, the simplest way to do that is to use the NUnit nuget package, which will install it into your test project and add the necessary reference.

Comment: Thank you Charlie, my mistake... Now the problem is: why nuget doesn't find any nunit package??
Ok, understand :-( Missing check on nuget origin.
Solved!